# How do I detect a wiggle motion on Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope

I need an algorithm that can detect a 'wiggle' gesture on Android, and by that I mean where the phone is held in portrait mode and the wrist is twisted left and right, like the motion of opening a round door handle. So I need to capture rotation back and forth around the z axis for a period of time.

A (crude) picture to illustrate the motion I need to capture:

[image: Rotation around the z axis]

I've tried a number of different algorithms that capture shaking, such as this "Shoogle For Yer Photos" solution seen [here](https://github.com/JMB-Technology-Limited/Shoogle-For-Yer-Photos-Android/blob/master/app/src/uk/co/jarofgreen/lib/ShakeDetectActivity.java) on Github, which work quite well, but capture shaking on every axis using the accelerometer. How would I restrict an algorithm like this to only detect rotation back and forth on the Z-axis, 'wiggling' for a minimum of say 4 seconds?

Here is an extract from the 'Shoogle For Yer Photos' code posted above, which shows how they handle shake detection:

```
private static final long KEEP_DATA_POINTS_FOR = 1500;
private static final long MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION = 7;
private static final float POSITIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD = (float) 2.0;
private static final float NEGATIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD = (float) -2.0;

public void checkForShake() {
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long cutOffTime = curTime - KEEP_DATA_POINTS_FOR;
    while(dataPoints.size() > 0 && dataPoints.get(0).atTimeMilliseconds < cutOffTime) dataPoints.remove(0);

    int x_pos =0, x_neg=0, x_dir = 0, y_pos=0, y_neg=0, y_dir=0, z_pos=0, z_neg = 0, z_dir = 0;
    for(DataPoint dp: dataPoints){
        if (dp.x > POSITIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD && x_dir < 1) {
            ++x_pos;
            x_dir = 1;
        }
        if (dp.x < NEGATIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD && x_dir > -1) {
            ++x_neg;
            x_dir = -1;
        }
        if (dp.y > POSITIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD && y_dir < 1) {
            ++y_pos;
            y_dir = 1;
        }
        if (dp.y < NEGATIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD && y_dir > -1) {
            ++y_neg;
            y_dir = -1;
        }
        if (dp.z > POSITIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD && z_dir < 1) {
            ++z_pos;
            z_dir = 1;
        }
        if (dp.z < NEGATIVE_COUNTER_THRESHHOLD && z_dir > -1) {
            ++z_neg;
            z_dir = -1;
        }
    }

    if ((x_pos >= MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION && x_neg >= MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION) ||
            (y_pos >= MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION && y_neg >= MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION) ||
            (z_pos >= MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION && z_neg >= MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION) ) {
        lastShake = System.currentTimeMillis();
        last_x = 0; last_y=0; last_z=0;
        dataPoints.clear();
        triggerShakeDetected();
        return;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Ever tried to remove `z_pos` and `z_neg` from your if statement?

Comment: would that not leave any shaking motion on the x and y axes being detected? I need it to only detect a back and forth rotation on the z-axis, regardless of any acceleration or rotation on any other axis.

Comment: Sorry thought you wanted only x and y. Then have you tried leaving only z_pos and z_neg in the last if statement?

Comment: @AlbAtNf I think that would only measure movement forwards and backwards along the z-axis, I need to detect only rotation on the z-axis, and furthermore, to have that rotation recognised as a 'wiggle' gesture (left/right/left/right/left/right for a few seconds).